# How can I implemented DDA at JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, drawing, dda

I tried to create implementation DDA line drawing algorithm at Java. I created JFrame form and dda.java classes. There is just one Button action at JFrame for this moment. And I am not sure about implementation DDA at JFrame class. I think, that it might be problem with drawPixel method but I am not sure about implementation at JFrame at all. I appreciate your comments.

this is draw line method at **dda.java**

```
 void drawLineDDA(Graphics2D g) {
        dx=(double)(x2-x1);
        dy=(double)(y2-y1);
        double m=Math.abs(dy/dx);
        double absx=Math.abs(dx);
        double absy=Math.abs(dy);
        double px = absx/p; 
        double py = absy/p; 
        int p=0;
        float slope = 1; 

        if(y1==y2){
            if(x1==x2) return; //it is not a line, nothing happened
            slope = 0;
            absx = 1;
            absy = 0;
            p=(int) (dx/absx); //p means number of steps
        }
        else if(x1==x2){
            slope = 2;
            absx = 0;
            absy = 1;
            p = (int) (dy/absy);
        }
        else{
            slope = (float) (dy/dx);
            absx=1;
            absy=slope*absx;
            p= (int) ((dy/absy > dx/absx) ? dy/absy : dx/absx);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <=p;i++){

            drawPixel(x1,y1,Color.BLACK);

            x1 += absx;
            y1 += absy;
        }}
```

method draw Pixel at **dda.java**

```
private void drawPixel(int x1, int y1, Color BLACK) {
      g.drawOval(x1, y1, x1+5, y1+5); //can be mistake right here?
    }
```

part of **JFrame class**

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int x1,x2,y1,y2;
 Graphics2D g;
 dda d;


    public NewJFrame() {
        this.d = new dda(20,30,20,50); //maybe this is not good?
        initComponents();

    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         g = (Graphics2D) jPanel1.getGraphics();
        d.drawLineDDA(g);   // and I am definielly not sure about this
    }
```

Comment: *"And I am not sure about implementation DDA at JFrame class."*  What are you not sure about?  This question is very vague.

Comment: comments in the code defines the lines which I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `getGraphics()` for custom painting, as it is a temporary buffer which is recycled on next repaint. Do you painting in `paintComponent()`. Override `paintComponent()` method of a `JComponent` or `JPanel`. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more information and examples. Also see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

There is also an issue in `drawPixel` method, as the dimensions of the oval depend on the coordinates. Try using constant dimension. `fillOval` may suit better. Here is an example:

```
private void drawPixel(Graphics2D g, int x1, int y1) {
    g.fillOval(x1, y1, 3, 3);
}
```